# I2C error with ADS1115 (read_i2c_block_data)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, adafruit

i have a trouble with an ads1115 (under raspberry pi).
Here is my python code

```
import smbus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x49
print bus.read_byte(address)
print bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0x00, 2)
```

and the follwing issue:

```
17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0x00, 2)
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

Therefore, i guess the I2C module is ok while i have a answer of "bus.read_byte" (here 17). Especially, the i2cdetec -y 1 works at all (and the output is the address 49.

The issue is still there if i use another address of the ads1115 (with another wiring as it is said in the example of adafruit).

Update: the module ADS1115 works with an Arduino (and the Adafruit librairy) and gives good measurements.

Have you got an idea?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but -- have your tried putting a small delay between your read calls? I've had timing problems with the RPi of this kind, which I've never really understood. Whatever the cause, I've noticed situations in which I2C operations can't be carried out in sequence as fast as the CPU will go.

Comment: I've just used time.sleep(1) without changes. Notice the ADS1115 module was tested successfully with an Arduino and the Adafruit librairy

Comment: Sorry -- it was only a stab in the dark. I've done some i2c programming on the RPi, but only in C. Is it possible to dig into the python smbus module and find out in detail whether error 121 is coming from the kernel module, or is the python module's interpretation of some condition it doesn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

this is my sample code while reading ads1115 on windows 10 iot and raspbery pi,
i think helpfull for you

```
var i2CSettings1 = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x48)
            {
                BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode,
                SharingMode = I2cSharingMode.Shared
            };



var i2C1 = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
                var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(i2C1);
                var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
```

// here is important, setup i2c device firstly

```
 _converter1 = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id, i2CSettings1);
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0xc4, 0x60 });
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 }); //rate
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x03, 0xff, 0xff });
```

// you must send this bytes. this must be send just one time

// and now we are reading data, you can read data in a loop but best way use alert pin. ads1115 has an alert pin and send and alert when ready for read, you can read alert pin with a digital input trigger by this code

```
_converter1.WriteRead(new byte[] { 0x0 }, bytearray1);
                            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                                Array.Reverse(bytearray1);
                            var value1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytearray1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Ground the ADDR-Pin (ADS1115) to your RaspberryPi Ground (i use PIN9)

```
Details of the Issue:
I had the same issue. But there is much more... 
I noticed when i run the python code, 
then run i2cdetect -y 1, my device changes address it becomes 48, 49, 4a, 4b (random)
```

I really hope this helps to some, as it took me a few days to know whats the issue.  Btw it is also a best practice to Ground all the unused channels.